# Working with two local repositiories and one remote repository

Tags: git, github, repository

I am building my code on top of an existing framework which is open source. However, I did not create a new branch of the framework. Instead, I use it like a library by linking the original source to my code during compile time. So there are two remote repositories, `my_code` and `framework`, which are independent.

I had to do some modifications to the source code of the framework locally, as I needed to access some private members of a class in the original source code.

Is there a way in which I can commit and push these changes to `my_code` repository so that my team members can clone that repo, apply changes to the framework source to their local `framework` repo and compile our code?

Comment: Why not just push changes to a branch in each repo and have your collaborators pull down those branches to their local?